# unable to publish updated Apk on Play Store

Tags: android, google-play

I changed  **android:versionCode="2"** from  **android:versionCode="1"** and also changed **android:versionName="1.1"** from **android:versionName="1.0"** but still it shows error.**Version 1** is not served to any device configuration [image]

Comment: i guess you are trying to publish version 1 it self

Comment: @PreethiRao then what is the issue?

Answer (score 3):

You need to deactivate the APK with versionCode 1 (versionName 1.0) before publish the APK with versionCode 2 (versionName 1.1)

Comment: do i need to wait ?and i could not find any option to publish app

Comment: and what is the option move at right side of my new apk?

Comment: it will move your app either to production or u can take it back

Comment: You need to press "Submit update" button and wait at least a couple of hours to see the update on the Play Store

Comment: but where is that option submit app

Comment: Above the button "Switch to simple mode" in your screenshot

Comment: you mean swithc to simple mode is the button submit app?

Comment: Above this button, there is another button "Submit update". You need to press this button to submit the new version of the app. If the button is disabled it means that you already pressed it and there are no modification to submit

Comment: sure i will check that..and did i follow steps of uploading updated apk to play store properly?am i forgetting something?is there any mistake?  tell me if i had..and i will accept answer when app will upload.now vote up

Comment: If the APK says "In prod" everything is all right, you only need to wait

Answer (score 1):

There are few steps to follow when You want publish updated application

### 1. At Your System side(in mainfest.xml of your application)

for example

android:versionCode="1" to android:versionCode="2"

android:versionName="1.0" to android:versionName="1.1"

### 2. At playstore side

Unpublish your old version apk..

### 3.At playstore side

Now upload your new updated **APK** followed 1st step...at playstore

Hope it help for you...